# Given a Bitcoin wallet address, can its other addresses be inferred from it?

Tags: wallet, address, public-key, privacy

A bitcoin wallet doesn't have one single address, but several. All these addresses can be obtained from the master public key, am I wrong?

Does knowing one of this addresses (not the master public key, just one of the addresses) provide any knowledge about the other ones? In other words, can I infer all or part of the addresses of a Bitcoin wallet knowing only one of them?

Comment: Hi Dan, I assume you deleted your question, because the topic I linked to answered your query. On this site, we are trying to help people find the answers to the topics they are looking for. I undeleted your question, because it is a good question, it just already happens to have an answer on our site. We do like to keep around multiple "sign-posts" that point at canonical questions, and yours would work as that. If you want to get an overview of how our site works, you can check out our [tour].